# Custom Compiler Warning To Remind To Use Method

Tags: c#

I have written an extension method on `ILogger` and need the complier to emit warning to use that extension method whenever someone use an ILogger instance. For example:

### Extension method on `ILogger`

```cs
public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static ILogger Here(this ILogger logger,
        [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
        [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
        [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0) {
        return logger
            .ForContext("MemberName", memberName)
            .ForContext("FilePath", sourceFilePath)
            .ForContext("LineNumber", sourceLineNumber);
    }
}
```

### Use `ILogger` instance will emit warning

```cs
// at the beginning of the class
private static Serilog.ILogger Log => Serilog.Log.ForContext<MyClass>();

// in the method

Log.Information("Warning: need to use Here() on ILogger") // the compiler emits warning to use Here()
Log.Here().Information("No warning here."); // this is good. No warning
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why not write your own Roslyn analyzer? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022

Comment: @LexLi thank you. I think Roslyn analyzer is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

1. Don't do it. Logs should identify themselves by the message/eventid. You don't need to know the line numbers - these can change over time anyway.
2. Setup your DI to return a logger that does the extra logging.
3. Setup the context in the constructor (this will not give you line numbers, but you can capture other info)
4. Write an analyzer. The official tutorial is [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix).
5. Write a script that scans for what you need and run it from time to time. You can even make this a test.

Comment: My goal is to include the method name in the current log message. I think the Roslyn analyzer is correct. Could you elaborate on number 2 and 3 please, any link or keyword is much appreciated? How to setup a logger that does extra logging? And what is the context in the instructor please? Number 5 is inefficient, I need it to remind developers as we code on the fly. Thank you for your help